# Exiting the a loop with my current code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Thank you for all who helped that was given and received by me on this, but I am once again stuck. This is in relation to my other question which I have since figured out an answer to on my own. Link is posted to get reference: [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269573/vba-filter-hide-and-count) I would like to know if anyone could help me figure out how to exit my loop. Everything is working as expected with the on thing in that I have created an infinate loop. I need it to exit the For...Next Loop once it reaches the last row or record. Thank you. Code is attached.

```
Sub DuplicateSystems()
'
' Created for use with the Vulnerability Remediation Asset Manager Site Baseline Summary
'

'Declared Variables
Dim lastRow As Long, currentRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Determines the Total number of Records
Dim recCount As Integer
With Sheets(1)
    recCount = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row - 2
End With

'Assigns a value to the lastRow variable
lastRow = recCount + 2

'Loops through the records, hides any system that has not been scanned in 30 days
For currentRow = 3 To lastRow + 1
    If Cells(currentRow, 8) > 30 Then

        'Assign the current system to a string value
        Dim sys As String, rng As Range
        sys = Cells(currentRow, 4).value

        'Figures out the Start Row for the current system
        Dim nRow As Long, sRow As Long, eRow As Long
        For nRow = 3 To lastRow
            If Range("D" & nRow).value = sys Then
                sRow = nRow
                Exit For
            End If
        Next nRow

        'Figures out the End Row for the current system
        For nRow = sRow To lastRow
            If Range("D" & nRow) <> sys Then
                eRow = nRow - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next nRow

        'Selects the all rows for that system
        Set rng = Range("D" & sRow & ":D" & eRow)
        rng.Select

        'Displays a message box with the range address
        MsgBox rng.Address

        'Hides the selection
        rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

        'Changes the currentRow to the end of the current system
        If eRow = Range("D" & lastRow) Then
            Exit For
        Else: currentRow = eRow
        End If

    'Shows all other systems
    Else: Cells(currentRow, 4).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

Next currentRow

'Counts the remaining the systems that are visible
Dim count As Integer
count = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D3:D" & lastRow).Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count

'Displays a message box with a number of the remaining systems
MsgBox count

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you are reassigning your looping variable, `currentRow` within the loop, so I can imagine it may never make it to `lastRow + 1`.

Comment: @MattCremeens How else would I tell it to work its way down the column? If you look at the above link, there I explain that with the data in the table only two of the systems should be shown after this code is ran. If one system is in D3:D5 how would I tell the code that the next system start is D6?

Comment: Do you have any duplicate systems? If so, that could be at least part of the problem as your start row (`sRow`) will go to a previous one with the same name.

Comment: @MattCremeens I would have duplicate systems. I cannot post actual data here but above is a link to my previous questions with a table that looks generally the same as what my reports would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know where your problem lies.

The last time you go through the loop if there is a value which is greater than 30 it will loop continuously because the part of your code where;

```
    For nRow = sRow To lastRow
        If Range("D" & nRow) <> sys Then
            eRow = nRow - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next nRow
```

For the last loop as you go down there is never a time were Range("D" & nRow) <> sys. As they will always be the same being that it is your last system. Because you never satisfy that IF statement you never redefine your eRow. Changing your code to

```
    For nRow = sRow To lastRow + 1
        If Range("D" & nRow) <> sys Then
            eRow = nRow - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next nRow
```

Should resolve this problem.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thank you. But the infinitate loop does not start till the end of the document when it get to row 372. Otherwise it works just fine.

Comment: @TroyPilewski I have changed my answer to what I now believe was your issue

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe your `currentRow` will always be your `sRow` so `sRow` is unnecessary. So you can remove

```
For nRow = 3 To lastRow
  If Range("D" & nRow).value = sys Then
    sRow = nRow
    Exit For
  End If
Next nRow
```

And replace `sRow` with `currentRow` thereafter.